# Skip checking a specific property in Jest snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

I need to test a snapshot which has also a property called `aria-labelledby` and created by some function that I cannot modify or mock. Everytime when I run the test, that property gets a new value which also I don't care what it is.

So, is there a way to mention the `aria-labelledby` to be not checked?

**Test**

```
it('My Test', () => {
    let wrapper: ReactWrapper;
    wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.find(App)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

**Snapshot**

```
.....
    }
    unmountOnExit={false}
    >
    <div
-       aria-labelledby="pr_id_1_label"      <===== SNAPSHOT VALUE
+       aria-labelledby="pr_id_2_label"      <===== NEW VALUE WHICH CAUSES THE TEST FAIL!!!!
        className="p-dialog p-component"
.....
```

Comment: what library adds that `aria-labelledby`? also I assume there is `<label id=` somewhere that is also dynamic, right?

Comment: @skyboyer `aria-labelledby` it's from `primereact` library `dialog` component. But I add for example `key` attribute dynamically somewhere else which also causes the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround using `enzyme-to-json` we [may specify `.map()` option](https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json/blob/HEAD/docs/map.md) to be able filtering props:

```
const removeLabelledBy = 
  ({"aria-labelledby": unused, ...restProps}) => restProps;
expect(
  toJson(wrapper, {
    mode: "deep",
    map: removeLabelledBy
  })
).toMatchSnapshot();
```